# When is the measure of spherical cap large?

Tags: probability, convex-geometry, geometric-probability, concentration-of-measure

It is known that in high dimensions, the measure of the spherical cap is small, due to the measure concentration for the sphere. In particular, we have the following inequality in $n$ dimension:
$$
1-\mu(A_t)\leq 2e^{-t^2n/2}
$$
where $A$ is any set with measure at least 1/2 and $A_t$ is its $t$-neighborhood. For the case of spherical caps, $A$ can be a hemisphere. Thus we have a small upper bound on the measure of spherical caps.

My question is, is there a lower bound for the measure of spherical caps? In particular I would like to know how small $t$ should be, such that $1-\mu(A_t)$ is at least a constant fraction of the measure of the whole sphere? Thanks.